# Отклоненные тревоги

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, тревоги

Нахватался отклоненных тревог и меня это тревожит...

Например, ставил тревогу "не является ответом" для:

- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1247767/420098

В вопросе содержиться опечатка (не хватает скобки), на что автору указывают в комментарии.
На данный момент первый вопрос закрыт по причине

> Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой

но ответ, который отличается именно этой скобкой - оставили

Какую пользу для сообщества несут такие "ответы", я так и не понял...
Разъясните, пожалуйста, может я что-то упускаю или недопонимаю?

Answer (score 7):

Ответ исправляет то, что не работает в вопросе, следовательно ответом он является.

Для опечаток надо не на ответы нападать, а закрывать вопросы с соответствующей причиной (или ставить соответствующую тревогу на вопрос, если недостаточно рейтинга). В общем-то, сейчас вопрос так и закрыт.